# How can I recover /home/owner directory from opt folder back to /?

Tags: permissions, home-directory, 14.10

I was about to burn a install flash drive with unetbootin when I somehow accidentally clicked on the wrong directory and apparently moved my `/home/owner` folder.

I located it in the `/opt` folder. I'm trying to move it back to `/`. I don't have the permission necessary to do that.

Can anyone advise me of the proper command for doing so in the terminal?

Comment: I need to make a correction to my question. I located my accidentally moved /home/owner folder in  the lib32 folder not the opt folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `/home` is still present:

```
 ls /home
```

If it doesn't exists then you should move folder with this command:

```
sudo mv /opt/home /home
```

If `/home` exists you should move user folder:

```
sudo mv /opt/home/owner /home/owner
```

[**sudo**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/sudo.8.html) give you superuser grant. Be careful using it, you could mess your system

Comment: or simpler: sudo nautilus  then do it as you known ;)